Bind uvicorn to a domain name with no explicit port
I have installed a python app on my ubuntu server and have bound it to a domain name which I allocated to the server using plesk's domain option. I run it using uvicorn with this command:
uvicorn app.main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000

I can access it, when it is running, with the following URL:
http://gerg-create.org:8000

I would like instead to access it like so:
http://gerg-create.org

(it does have an SSL certificate but I haven't yet fixed it up to serve https endpoints. Note also I can't guarantee it's running at any given time because I am working on it, but that's probably not material to this question)
I'm new to deploying on ubuntu because until now I was using a hosting provider instead of a server.
What's the route I should travel? Is it possible to achieve what I want by modifying the call to uvicorn, or the way the domain name is bound to the server? Or I should I try another route, perhaps using wsgi?
The actual code is on https://github.com/axfreeman/simulation-api

What version of Ubuntu are you using?

It's Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
